# SMTP connectivity issue in Zenoss ("Connection unexpectedly closed")

Tags: linux, monitoring, sendmail, smtp

I am using Zenoss for monitoring purpose. I have been using its mail service for a long time. Suddenly my mail service in zenoss stopped and started showing `<class 'smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected'> - Connection unexpectedly closed` and no mails are outgoing. When I ran the mail command via CLI, the mail goes to the email address. While executing the zenoss script for mailer won't work and throws out the error as shown above.

My server is RHEL 5.3 x86_64, with Zenoss 4.2 & sendmail email server.

#### Sendmail logs & Zenoss email conf

```
Apr 11 07:14:30 XXXhostnameXX sendmail[13582]: r3BBDgia013582: lost input channel from localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1] to MTA after mail
Apr 11 07:14:30 XXXhostnameXX sendmail[13582]: r3BBDgia013582: from=<fromaddress@emaildomain.com>, size=146972, class=0, nrcpts=0, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1]
```

Zenoss is following basic smtp connection as emailing is done by local sendmail server (localhost) in port 25. No specific configuration is used.

Comment: 1) Could you post the relevant sendmail log entries? 2) Could you post details of your Zenoss email configuration? [It may help "non Zenoss" experts]

Comment: @Andrzej A. Filip :Updated with logs.

Answer (score 0):

It may be is a client side timeout after issuing "MAIL FROM:".
Knowing **exact** value of reply delay should provide a  valuable hint.

Could you send a test message in verbose mode? 
[It should provide SMTP session transcript]

```
#!/bin/sh
# -v - be verbose (provide SMTP transcript)
# -i - 'single dot' line is NOT end of email
# -t - get recipients list from email headers
# -f - set envelope sender email address (for "MAIL FROM:" in SMTP session)
/usr/sbin/sendmail -v -i -t -ffromaddress@emaildomain.com <<END
Subject: test
From: fromaddress@emaildomain.com
to: xxx@example.net

test
END
```

Comment: Thank you .This script was really helpful in testing my sendmail .In its output , otherfew `address unresolvable for @emaildomain.com` , test email successfully reached xxx@example.net.Do you know a way to extend the time out in email Server side ?

Comment: 1) Add -8.20 sendmail command line option to trace DNS lookups. Fixing DNS entries or used email addresses may fix your problem. 2) I know sendmail, I do not know Zenoss.